# How to use GROUP_CONCAT without GROUP BY in my case?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my following Query

```
SELECT CONCAT( "[",
               GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT( `expenses`.`expense_type`, `expenses`.`amount`,'date',`expenses`.`updated_time`))  ,
               "]"
             )
FROM expenses
GROUP BY `expenses`.`expense_type`
```

How to use this query without group by like i need all rows inside single json array with json object.

Comment: Have you tried removing the group by clause? Did it work? Why not?

Comment: fine it's working.